# How recover composer.json by existing project on symfony2?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I have to work on a project on symphony 2 without composer's config, but with folders vendor/* in the repository.

I want to re-install the composer and generate a configuration for an existing package. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if command for vendor -> composer.json exists. But you can list installed dependencies via `composer show --installed`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I recreate composer.json from the content of the vendor directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782095/how-can-i-recreate-composer-json-from-the-content-of-the-vendor-directory)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should create bare `composer.json` by hand or using command `composer init`.

And then you can list all the packages under the `vendor` folder by `composer show --installed`.

Then just generate require section for your `composer.json` with listed values. And you are done. You can use regular expressions to do it easier.

```
composer show --installed \
   | awk '{printf "\"%s\": \"^%s\",\n", $1, $2}' \
   | sed -r 's:\^v:^:g' \
   >> packages.list
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 composer update
 Loading composer repositories with package information
 Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
 Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 8 removals       
   - Removing yiisoft/yii2-jui (2.0.7)
   - Removing bower-asset/jquery-ui (1.12.1)
   - Removing phpoffice/phpspreadsheet (1.0.0)
   - Removing psr/simple-cache (1.0.0)
   - Removing guzzlehttp/guzzle (5.0.0)
   - Removing guzzlehttp/ringphp (1.1.0)
   - Removing guzzlehttp/streams (3.0.0)
   - Removing react/promise (v2.5.1)
   - Updating swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.8 => v5.4.9): Downloading (100%)         
 Writing lock file
 Generating autoload files
```

I think you can execute `composer update`, it will show you  all packages, and then  `composer install ...` one by one

Comment: composer update with remove all installed dependency that is not in the composer.json