# How can I recreate composer.json from the content of the vendor directory?

Tags: composer-php

I have a project where I am using `composer`.

However, I have lost my `composer.json`.

Is there a way to recreate `composer.json` from the content of the `vendor` directory?

Comment: neither the composer.lock files?

Comment: Try using a VCS next time. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408450/why-should-i-use-version-control.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Identifying the *installed* dependencies can be easily achieved by inspecting

```
vendor
└── composer
    └── installed.json
```

However, you will be faced with the following problems:

#### Direct and indirect dependencies

`installed.json` lists *all* installed dependencies, that is, both

- direct *and*
- indirect

dependencies.

Direct dependencies are dependencies that are explicitly listed in the
`require` and `require-dev` sections.

Indirect dependencies are dependencies of your direct dependencies.

That is, while you could programmatically parse `installed.json` and
collect the dependencies listed therein, you will need to decide for
yourself whether these are direct or indirect dependencies, or in other
words, whether you want to *explicitly* require these dependencies in
`composer.json`.

#### Production and development dependencies

`installed.json` lists *all* installed dependencies, that is, depending
on whether you ran

```
$ composer install
```

or

```
$composer install --no-dev
```

before you lost your `composer.json`, `installed.json` will contain
direct and indirect dependencies listed in

- `require` and `require-dev` *or*
- `require`

sections, respectively.

That is, you will need to decide for yourself whether these are
dependencies which should be listed in the

- `require` *or*
- `require-dev`

sections.

See

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install
- [Using "require-dev" to install packages in composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117871/using-require-dev-to-install-packages-in-composer)

to find out more about the purpose and the differences between these
sections.

#### Version Constraints

`installed.json` lists *all* installed dependencies with the *exact*
versions installed.

However, the `composer.json` you lost in all likelihood did not list
dependencies with exact versions, but using one of the many possibilities
for specifying version constraints.

That is, you will need to decide for yourself whether you want to use exact versions, or relax the constraints, for example, by using

- the `~` operator
- the `^` operator
- etc.

See

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#writing-version-constraints

to find out more about version constraints.

Answer (score 2):

**Hoppe!!**


I had a similar problem with a Laravel project
In order to solve it:

1. Create a separate base project, with the same version of *Laravel* to work with, in case you don't work with *Laravel*, you can skip to step 3.
2. Copy the contents of the file to have a stable working base
3. Run the [a python script gist](https://gist.github.com/yebt/9729a2ba13f0fc7e42e010e261bcd5b9)  , giving it the `installed.json` path, this will return the `require` and `require-dev` of the project
4. Copy and paste the requirements inside `composer.json`. In case of working with *Laravel*, be careful not to affect the require brought from the base app.

Comment: Pido disculpas de antemano si por mi respuesta o mi forma de codificar en el github provisto ofendo a alguien, realmente no es mi intención, solo quiero ser de ayuda, gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it with this one-liner that reads vendor/composer/installed.php and reinstalls everything:

```
php -r '$pkgs = require "vendor/composer/installed.php";

foreach($pkgs["versions"] as $pkg => $pkg_content)
{
  if($pkg == "__root__")
    continue;

  if(empty($pkg_content["version"]))
    continue;

  exec("composer require $pkg");
}
'
```